# Highcharts - Pie Chart - link in tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip, pie-chart

I am trying to add a link in a tooltip. The problem is that if I switch to mobile, and click on the tooltip, it's like I click through it. It doesn't send me to another page, only moves the tooltip wherever I click.

```
chart: {
        type:'pie'
},

title: {
  text: 'Full HTML tooltip with border, background and shadow'
},

tooltip: {
  useHTML: true,
  style: {
    padding: 0,
    pointerEvents: 'auto'
  },
  formatter: function() {
    return '<a href="http://google.com"> click here </a>'
  }
},
```

Does anyone how any trick to actually trigger the link I click?

Here's the fiddlle http://jsfiddle.net/zfwx6s9q/1/

Thanks.

Comment: can you able to click link which is inside tooltip. see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24488098/3898339) it may help

Comment: I need to have the link on the tooltip, not on the slice.

Comment: Set `tooltip.followPointer` to false, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zfwx6s9q/3/ (tested with Android)

Comment: It worked, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You may try to alter the way how tooltip is displayed.

```
   tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      positioner:function(){ return {x:100, y:100}; },
      hideDelay:3000,
      style: {
        padding: 0,
        pointerEvents: 'auto'
      },
      formatter: function() {
        return '<a href="http://google.com"> click here </a>'
      }
    },
```

- Set the tooltip postion to be fixed
- Increase the hide delay

http://jsfiddle.net/zfwx6s9q/2/

Comment: Thanks for comment, unfortunately I need to display it where it has been clicked.