# Highchart-piechart : use a link on each slice on click

Tags: php, symfony, highcharts, hyperlink

after spending a long time on the web to find an answer for my problem, I'm writing this because i found no issues. I use highchart in my web site to realise some piecharts with data extracted from my DB. I have nice piecharts but I would like, if this is possible to, when we click on a part of a piechart that we are redirected to another HTML page. As example, we got a piechart that show us in a company the number ( in%) that the company sell like : 40% : computer, 40% : cars and 20% food like example (totally false example I'm just looking for the method). And then if we click on the slice of the 40% of the cars we are redirected to another page that show us like example people who bought the cars.

This is actually my php code to realise this :

```
public function accueilAction()
{

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('PharmagestsiteBundle:Pharmacie');

    $pharma = $repository->findAll();
    $avecdex = 0;
    $toutesph = 0;
    foreach ($pharma as $pharmacie) {
        $total =
            $pharmacie->getExtractionDexter();
        if ($total == 1) {
            $avecdex += 1;
        }
        $toutesph++;
    }
    $data = [
        ['Pharmacie avec <br> Dexter installé', $avecdex, $url = "localhost/projet/web/app_dev.php/pharmacie"],
        ['Pharmacie sans <br> Dexter installé', $toutesph - $avecdex],
    ];
    $ob = new Highchart();
    $ob->chart->renderTo('container');
    $ob->chart->type('pie');
    $ob->colors('#006400', '#FF0800');
    $ob->title->text('Pharmacie ayant Dexter installé');

    $ob->title->style(array('fontSize' => '30px','fontFamily' => 'arial'));
    $ob->series(array(array("data" => $data)));

    $ob->plotOptions->pie(array(
        'allowPointSelect' => true,
        'cursor' => 'pointer',
     /*   'point' => ['events' => ['click' => function () {
            window.location.href == this.options.url;
        }
        ]],
        'events' => array('click' => function () {
            window.location.href == "localhost/projet/web/app_dev.php/pharmacie";
        }),*/
        'dataLabels' => array('enabled' => true, 'format' => '{point.name}</b>:<br>{point.percentage:.1f} %', 'style' => array( 'fontSize' => '15px','fontFamily' => 'arial')),
        'style' => array('black'),

    ));
```

So I think you understood that I would like to redirect through localhost/projet/web/app_dev.php/pharmacie

Any help or even advice would be apprecied !

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24488098/3898339) answer. Comment

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already saw this example and I tried to do like @SteveP with an "url" in my data like :                                                                                                               $data = [
        ['Pharmacie avec <br> Dexter installé', $avecdex, $url = "localhost/projet/web/app_dev.php/pharmacie"],
        ['Pharmacie sans <br> Dexter installé', $toutesph - $avecdex],                          but I'm doing this with php and the code that he wrote isn't in php so I don't think I can use it. I tried to convert it in PHP but it seems doesn't work...

Comment: ok this is php code but what is the output code in front end. Is this matching with above mentioned example (data:[{...}])

Comment: In the front end, the result is the same. In fact, to get something correct I want to convert the code that you show me in a php code. I already tried above but something is missing I think because it doesn't work. To answer you, yes its match

Comment: is it coming like `data:[{name:'Pharmacie avec <br> Dexter installé',y:'some_value',url:'localhost/projet/web/app_dev.php/pharmacie'}]` ??

Comment: Oh I understood, no. When I var_dump() my $data I got this :     array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(36) "Pharmacie avec <br> Dexter installé"
    [1]=>
    int(3)
    [2]=>
    string(42) "localhost/projet/web/app_dev.php/pharmacie"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(36) "Pharmacie sans <br> Dexter installé"
    [1]=>
    int(1)
  }
}   I never json_encode this so it can explain why I dont get what you propose above

Comment: are you able to solve the problem

Comment: No I'm not, that's why I asked to you in this forum to get helped by one of you. If you have an idea or if you know something that would be interesting